# Whole document scrolls in IE11, but not Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I have an HTML page that is generated from two different frameworks.  I can't make huge changes to it, because of those frameworks, but I can adjust the html with jquery.  Basically, I have an application that has a header, and a second reporting application that has a header (let's call it the subheader), content, and a footer.  The behavior I'm seeking is that the document is positioned to consume the full viewport, the footer is stuck to the bottom, and the content div expands or contracts as needed, and has overflow so that if the real data is to big for the content div, it scrolls.  My solution works in Chrome, but in IE, the document itself (incorrectly) gets a scrollbar, in addition to the content frame (correctly) getting a scrollbar.

Appreciate any help you can provide.

jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wfm39gbh/).

Code:

```
<body bottommargin="0" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" rightmargin="0">
    <div style="width:100%;height:125px;background-color:#FFC;"></div>
</body>

<FORM NAME="rdForm" method="POST">
    <MainBody>
        <DIV id="divOuterContainer" CLASS="NF_display_table_container">
            <DIV id="divHeader" CLASS="NF_top">
                 <SPAN>My SubHeader</SPAN>
            </DIV>
            <DIV id="divContentContainer">
                <DIV id="divContent">
                    <DIV id="divInteractive" CLASS="NF_body2">
                        <div style="width:100%;height:1200px;background-color:#FCC;">
                        </div>
                    </DIV>
                </DIV>
             </DIV>
         <DIV id="divFooter" CLASS="NF_bottom2">
             <SPAN>My Footer
             </SPAN>
         </DIV>
       </DIV>
        </MainBody></FORM>
```

Javascript:

```
function reflow() {
    var wsize = $(window).height();
    var headers = $("#divContent").position().top;
    var my_footer = $("#divFooter").height();

    var new_height = Math.ceil(wsize - (headers + my_footer));


    $("#divContent").css('height', new_height);
    $("#divInteractive").css('height', new_height);


}
$(document).ready(

function () {
    // Run immediately on DOM ready…
    reflow();
    // And again on page load and resize events
    $(window).bind("load resize", reflow);
}

);
```

And css:

```
.hide {
    display: none;
}
.NF_body2 {
    overflow: auto;
}
.NF_top {
    background-color:#CFF;
}
.NF_bottom2 {
    background-color:#CFF;
}
.NF_container2 {
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: `MainBody` isn't a valid HTML element, so it's possible that you're in quirks mode, which changes the rules IE uses to render your markup. Can you verify whether or not IE is rendering in Standards mode (use F12 to launch the developer tools)?

Comment: According to [this](http://dorward.me.uk/www/bookmarklets/qors/) I'm in standards mode.  Thanks

Comment: @user2666791 To know if you're in standards mode, open your developer tools and look to the top-right (or in the emulation tab).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try overflow: hidden on the body tag rather

Comment: Are you after a one page html doc? If so you can set the height of the body to be the height of the viewport using jquery, then the nested div with the overflowed content should scroll as you prescribe according to its content. Setting overflow: hidden to the body tag then will get rid of the main overflow bar. If you arent after a one page doc, you may get irregularities with the way different viewports calculate the content, leading to inconsistencies like this...

Comment: That was it, thanks.  I mistakenly thought you were suggesting "overflow: hidden" on my NF_body2 tag in the CSS, since I didn't already have a body tag.  When I added that, it worked.

Comment: also get rid of the mainBody tag and enclose it in the body tag. If what is currently the body tag is supposed to be the header, change it to the <header> tag.

Answer (score 1):

From what i can see you are missing the **-ms-overflow-style property** in your CSS.
Try this:

```
    .NF_body2 {
    overflow: auto;
    -ms-overflow-style: auto;
}
```

And if you need to add it somewhere else just do the same.
And if you want to read more on that matter check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh771902%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)!